# mongodb pojo codec conversion missing id field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java

I have a following document structure in mongo

```
{
    "_id" : 4771902,
    "upc" : "test-upc-v1",
    "reportingCategory" : {
        "id" : 14,
        "department" : "Footwear"
    }
}
```

My java class looks like

```
public class Product {
    private Long _id;
    private String upc;
    private ReportingCategory reportingCategory;
}

public class ReportingCategory {
    private Long id;
    private String department;
}
```

I am using mongo pojo codec for conversion. "id" field under ReportingCategory is being returned as null.
Rest every other data is available. I can see that data when I convert it into RawBsonDocument, but seems like it gets lost in pojo conversion.
"id" field has no index on it, and is not used to uniquely identify this document. 
Has anyone faced something similar and any work around for it ?

P.S. I am using mongo 3.6, with 3.6 async driver.

Comment: Cant reproduce here. Did you register the pojo codec with codec registry ? Please add the code where you register/save and query.

Comment: Yes I did register codec register, I am able to retrieve every other data except id field under reporting category. On doing some more research this seems like a bug in mongo db java driver. If pojo has any member with name "id" it by defaults map it to "_id" field of mongo document. This is what is happening here.

Comment: It worked fine for me in 3.5 driver. See if you test with that driver version.

Answer (score 4):

This is indeed a feature/bug in mongodb java driver.
Anyone looking for a reason and a solution for this can find one here https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-2750